# How to change order of elements using a child theme

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am creating a child-theme to storefront, and for my specific purpose I want the meta information (tag, category, etc) to be available at the bottom of the page, and not right after the 'Add to cart' button.

I investigated the theme and it looked like this data is added in the hooks.php file inside /inc/structure, but when I modify it by placing my hooks.php in the child theme, nothing gets changed.

I have added the entry to init.php.. I've tried placing in all the content of the hooks.php in storefront, I've also tried using remove_action... But it's not working.

How do I change the order of inclusion of the elements using a child theme for storefront?

Comment: You should contact the theme author or at least post the relevant code which you are talking about, otherwise your question will just be closed as off topic

Comment: Contact the theme author? Why can't I just ask it here? Storefront is not a small-time theme. It is the default theme of WooCommerce, and I am sure that a lot of dev have worked on it. My question is quite clear without code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't get an answer to this yet, but I did find it out on my own with a lot of research and some luck.

The secret is in the priority order of the hooks. The last argument which is a number. The lower the number, the higher up the item will appear. I was also able to unhook the content using 'remove_action' from one hook and add to another.

Making a child theme for Storefront (woocommerce theme) required referring to three sources. My own child theme, the storefront theme, and the woocommerce template which is a part of the woocommerce plugin.

That complicates everything a little more, but it was fun looking for things and discovering.